# Submit form on select change via AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, submit

Let's say I have this form :

```
<form action="Change-status.php" method="post">
        <select class="changeStatus" name="changeStatus">
                <option value="0">Starting</option>
                <option value="1">Ongoing</option>
                <option value="2">Over</option>
        </select>
        <input class="projectId" type="hidden" name="projectId" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"/>
</form>
```

I am currently using this script to submit the form, but it implies refreshing :

```
$('select').change(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

What I want to do is to send the form on select change **without refreshing the page**. I know I have to use AJAX to do so but I couldn't exactly figure out how to implement it.

Could you orient me on how to do this?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

After taking comments into consideration, I ended up with the following code :

Html :

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <select class="changeStatus" name="changeStatus">
                <option value="0">Starting</option>
                <option value="1">Ongoing</option>
                <option value="2">Over</option>
        </select>
        <input class="projectId" type="hidden" name="projectId" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"/>
</form>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.changeStatus').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Change-status.php',
                data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val(), projectId: $('input[name$="projectId"]').val()},
                dataType: 'html'
         });
    });
});
```

PHP :

```
<?php
    include('../Include/Connect.php');

    $changeStatus=$_POST['selectFieldValue'];
    $id=$_POST['projectId'];

    $sql='UPDATE project SET progress="'.$changeStatus.'" WHERE id="'.$id.'"';

    mysql_query($sql) or die("Erreur: ".mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked in firebug to see if the request is actually being made?

Comment: I checked in Firebug and apparently, I get an "Undefined index: projectId" error message. I guess my input type is ignored, should I add it in `data`?

Comment: `data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val()},` < you arn't sending a variable called projectId... try `data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val(), projectId: 123},` the `data` object in options for the ajax request defines the GET/POST variables that are passed in the request

Comment: Try with a fixed value and post your exact code above and I can have a look - it should work so I can't really say why it isn't without seeing the code

Comment: I updated the code above, it is now exactly what I am using.

Comment: Ok and you are getting `Undefined index: projectId`? are you able to access `$_POST['selectFieldValue'];` in the php?

Comment: I'm not getting the `Undefined index` error message anymore, and the `selectFieldValue` takes the right values, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: If you're not getting the undefined error then the post is working. If you want the value from the hidden field you will need to get it `$('input:name=[projectId]').val()` or use `.serializeArray()` to turn the whole form into an array like object:- http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. Now everything seems to communicate as expected... except, I'm getting a syntax error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name`. I'll look into that.

Comment: `projectId: $('input[name$="projectId"]').val()` seems to work, the returned values are correct, I guess my problem is now solved. Thanks ! One thing though, is there a way to change the CSS class of my `<div/>` (containing the form) according to certain conditions (switch would be great) via the success setting? Again, thank you.

Comment: Absolutely - see here about changing classes using jQuery:- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting cross browser `onchange` events  and AJAX requests working isn't trivial. I'm recommend you use a javascript framework of some kind, which abstracts away all of the cross browser issues so you don't have to worry about them.

**Try a js framework**

[Jquery](http://www.jquery.com) is just one such framework which has methods such as [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) which attaches a handler to the change event for elements like `<select>` and [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) which performs a GET request.

Here's a little bit of code to get you started:-

```
// The $ is the shorthand for a jquery function, you can then use jquery 
// selectors which are essentially the same as css selectors, so here
// we select your select field and then bind a function to 
// it's change event handler
$('select.changeStatus').change(function(){

    // You can access the value of your select field using the .val() method
    alert('Select field value has changed to' + $('select.changeStatus').val());

   // You can perform an ajax request using the .ajax() method
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
      url: 'changeStatus.php', // This is the url that will be requested

      // This is an object of values that will be passed as GET variables and 
      // available inside changeStatus.php as $_GET['selectFieldValue'] etc...
      data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val()},

      // This is what to do once a successful request has been completed - if 
      // you want to do nothing then simply don't include it. But I suggest you 
      // add something so that your use knows the db has been updated
      success: function(html){ Do something with the response },
      dataType: 'html'
    });

});
```

**Some references that will be better than my explanations**

Please note for this code to work you will need to include the jquery library on you page with a `<script>` tag.

See [here for a quick start guide on using jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery)

[And here for a beginners tutorial on how to use jquery's `ajax()` method](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/)

Comment: This form, actioning the change-status.php file, is actually meant to update the database, I simply need this task to be done. There is nothing to display, so how can I proceed without displaying anything? Also, I'm not sure I fully understand what the success setting does in my case, how can I manipulate it? Thanks.

Comment: The `data` property in the ajax request is the data that is either sent via a GET string or as POST variables. So in the example above if you use `change-status.php` as the url, then the value of your select field will be available from `$_GET['selectFieldValue']` inside `change_status.php`. So use that to update your database. Then you probably want to do something inside `success:` to indicate to the user that the ajax request has completed.

Comment: @morgi See edits to my answer above. I've added some more comments to the code and some references to some tutorials that should help you get off the ground. Good luck!