# Form using AJAX / jQuery to set session with dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I believe this question will involve AJAX, jQuery, PHP, and sessions.  I've tried for days and can't crack this.  Starting fresh after many walks.

I simply want a form with a dropdown box that does NOT refresh/reload the screen.  Saves the selection as a SESSION and "selects" or highlights the dropdown choice based on the session they just set.

So in a nutshell...
- Client selects the option (must use onchange event instead of clicking submit)
- using jQuery / AJAX this helps to prevent the page from reloading (correct?)
- dropdown choice is "remembered" because it uses the session to compare and "selects" it.
- Also able to echo / print the session on the same page.

I'm going to be using this simple example in multiple steps of an ordering form which uses check boxes, radios, input boxes, and dropdown menu.

If anyone knows of a simple example using a dropdown box, that would get me started.

The attempts I had before would only set a session using the first or last of the dropdown list instead of the one chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The way that ive done something similar in the past is by having a user session (As a class on the backend) that gets initlaized on every page load.  This way i can save variables like the aforementioned.

But this also allows you to have an array of objects in the background which spawn off of this user class and can be used to replace other items.

1)For the simple page you need to build a control which reads the default value for the select box off of your array session.

2)Write a very simple PHP page to handle changing the value (im assuming you're only storing this to the session and not the DB)

```
<?php
session_start();
$client = $_GET['cc'];
$_SESSION['package']['overrideClient'] = $client; 
echo $_SESSION['package']['overrideClient'];
?>
```

3)Bind a change to your drop down
    
    var change= {
    changeValue : function(obj){
    var val = $(obj).val();
    $.ajax({
     url:"path.php?Page="+val, 
     success:function(){
    //Do something here
   }});}};

4)Now that this item is 'in' the session any other page can just be called dynamically using $_SESSION['package']['overrideClient'];  or by initializing a class using your session package to build a more complex handling for the user.

This should get you pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am not quite understanding how to code that in particular.  On this tutorial link, there might be a way to to this but I have one question about a certain line.  http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html

on their example on line 24 and 25...  it has     $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
     $('#results').html(data);

Is this the part of the script where I would add SESSION data?  I'm hoping the user can select dropdown menu, onchange or change triggers it, session is set.

Comment: The session has to be done in PHP.  Since PHP is a server side language and you are working on the client side you need to first pass the value back to php via Javascript (or refresh the page which is bad)  Use this : function test(){  $.post('process.php', { "value" : $('$selectbox').val()}) });   and on your selectbox  add onchange="test();"   In Process.php you are going to look for a $_POST of 'value' and then save that to your session.

Comment: This stackoverflow page looks almost identical to what I need.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365464/submit-form-on-select-change-via-ajax  Using this, I was able to have dropdown menu work, and save the variable to a database.  However, i'm still trying to use it to set SESSION variable and not save to db.  Once the php page sets the session, is there a way to display the session variable below the dropdown menu?  I tried echo but I'm guessing that saving the $_POST isn't all that is needed correct?  Do I still have to enter some code in the script to retrieve the session variable?

Comment: The reason for not wanting to save to the db and only do sessions is because when a shopper goes in and browses.. that would really fill up a database with "temp" data and doesn't seem efficient.  Is that a good assumption?  using sessions only until commitment?

Comment: You're fine using only sessions.   In this example when the user saves to the database use my chunk of code to instead save it to the session and you'll be good :)