# Put in javascript Variable in SQL prepeared statement (java)

Tags: java, javascript, html, mysql, spring-mvc

how can I put the selectItem variable:

```
        var e = document.getElementById("categoryName");
        var selectItem = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

In:

```
var theData = [ // Start of JavaScript data object

        <%
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pyramid", "root", "test");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT timeStamp, value FROM status WHERE idCategory = (SELECT idCategory FROM  category WHERE name =' " SELECTITEMVARIABLE " ')");
```

In prepearedstatement where it says SELECTITEMVARIABLE, how can I use the selectItem from the javascript?
Sorry for bad english and Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense in the form you've got now. You're going to need to communicate the client-side information back to your server via a form post or an XHR.

Comment: Not possible the way you are envisioning it above. Plus, if you are directly substituting the value in the query, why are you using prepared statements in the first place?

Comment: I have controllers on the client-side, can I use them instead? Or should I go for Ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not at all Possible.**

Java script Plays on client side and JSP plays on server side.

What you need is you have to make a server request.And send that string a `query parameter`.

You might misunderstand that jsp and javascript existed on same document.Yes but JSP part compiles on server side itself comes to client.

**So solutions are** :either go for html form submit or go fo Ajax request.

Comment: Okay thanks, I should go for Ajax I think. Im trying to put this data in a google chart, you guys dont know if Google has a function for that? or do I need to do it by my self? Thanks a lot by the way

Comment: @benskiiii even you though  you have to specify the control at form level right ?

Comment: hmm, what do you suggest? Whats the easiest?

Comment: Now a days lot of people preferring Asynchronous data loading.That is AJAX.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, gonna start from there then. If I could upvote I would do that for sure, you cant help me on the way with some code?

Comment: This guide you furthur and see links for there for beginners :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365464/submit-form-on-select-change-via-ajax

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the client side value over to the server (via POST), read it from the request parameter, and then append it to the SQL.