# How to implement such request to DB

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

In view I have two `foreach`: first outputs all categories, the second one, should output every brand from **current** category.

Example:

```
// Controller
$categories = DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->select('categories.name as cat')
                ->groupBy('categories.name')
                ->get();
$brands = DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('brands', 'products.b_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                ->select('brands.name as brand')
                ->where('categories.id', '=', '1')<-- the problem part
                ->groupBy('brands.name')
                ->get();

//view
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li><a>{{ $category->cat}}</a>
        <ul class="sort-section">
            <li><a href="#"><strong>All {{$category->cat}}</strong></a></li>
            @foreach($brands as $brand)
                <li><a href="#">{{ $brand->brand }}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

I don't know how to output it properly. Right now I'm getting records, `where categories.id = 1`(I did it to check if my code works at all), but instead of `1` I should use `id` of **current** `category`. In other words, if I would like to make it happen no matter what, I would implement the second query in first `foreach` in my view(which is crazy).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just so I understand the question, do you want the list of Brands displayed to be only the ones associated with the selected Category?

Comment: @Birdman Yes, that's the hardest part for me: during first `foreach` I'm getting values of categories. And for evey category I have to get different brands. that's the `where` part in second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with just one query, like this:

// Controller

```
$getAll = DB::table('categories')
                    ->leftJoin('products', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->leftJoin('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.b_id')
                    ->groupBy('brands.name')
                    ->groupBy('categories.name')
                    ->get([
                        'categories.id as id',
                        'categories.name as cat',
                        'brands.name as brand'
                    ]);

        $categories = [];
        if (count($getAll)) {
            foreach ($getAll as $single) {
                if (!isset($categories[$single->id])) {
                    $categories[$single->id] = new \StdClass();
                }
                $categories[$single->id]->cat = $single->cat;
                $categories[$single->id]->brands[] = $single->brand;
            }
        }
```

Then in your view do this

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 <li><a>{{ $category->cat}}</a>
   <ul class="sort-section">
     <li><a href="#"><strong>All {{$category->cat}}</strong></a></li>
     @foreach($category->brands as $brand)
        <li><a href="#">{{ $brand }}</a></li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm getting: `Undefined variable: brands`. I tried returning in controller `return view('pages.index', compact(['getAll', 'categories']));`

Comment: 1. You don't need $getAll on your blade, 2. you might left somewhere $brands written, in my example there is no variable named $brands, there is only $brand

Comment: Duuuudeeeee!! It works. It was complaining about `brand` simply because commenting in `blade` doesn't work for Laravel — deleted my old commented section and everything works as smooth as it could be. Thanks a lot, now I may work on something else during this weekend.(because otherwise I would have been working on this)

Comment: Great, I'm so glad. Have a nice weekend ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways you can approach this.

The first is the uglier way, but still does the trick. You can split this into two different parts. The user first selects the Category, which submits a post request, and then you capture the Category ID and then query and return only the brands associated with that category. This does force a page reload.

The second is the cleaner way, and it's using AJAX. Using JQuery makes this easy, and here's an answer that can show you how to get started:
[Using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365464/submit-form-on-select-change-via-ajax)