# my ajax submit onchange select is working on the first row only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML table that has a column with select options that submits using onchange event using ajax.
the code works perfectly for the first row of each page (since pagination is applied on the table) but any other row is useless.

I had submitted a question related to this matter earlier and I stumbled on this question by chance that thankfully helped me a lot but not for the entire table.
this is the original Q&A link:
[Submit form on select change via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365464/submit-form-on-select-change-via-ajax)

my customized HTML code

```
<td>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <select class="changeStatus" name="changeStatus" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <option value="<?php echo $row["STATUS"]; ?>" > <?php echo $row["STATUS"]; ?></option>
            <option value="new">new</option>
            <option value="checking">checking</option>
            <option value="processing">processing</option>
            <option value="done">done</option>
          </select>
           <input class="order_Id" type="hidden" name="order_Id" value="<?php echo $row["ORDER_ID"];?>"/>
           </form>
          </td>
```

ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select.changeStatus').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'test2.php',
                data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val(), order_Id: $('input[name$="order_Id"]').val()},
                success: function(html){alert('Select field value has changed to' + $('select.changeStatus').val()); },
                dataType: 'html'
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

note:the alert is only echoing the first row vlue as well.

php code

```
<?php
$connection =   mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'' ,'project_name');


    $changeStatus=$_POST['selectFieldValue'];
    $id=$_POST['order_Id'];

    $sql='UPDATE new_order SET STATUS="'.$changeStatus.'" WHERE ORDER_ID ="'.$id.'"';
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);


?>
```

I have searched for days and this was my one and only successful code so far.
thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have multiple records and multiple form on same page and when onChange event fired you are using same name of select field. make field name unique and your javascript code will be able to post accordingly.

Comment: sadly this is the only form in this page and the ORDER_ID row is unique and when I inspect it on Firefox it shows the right ID for each row.tho I changed the name attribute and class to make sure not conflicting with other attributes but no result either. thanks for stopping by.

Comment: Sarah can you send me source code (ctrl+u) when you open this page in firefox this code will help to understand what is happening.

Comment: sure no problem but how? I'm quite new to SOF.

Comment: Just received.
Will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: sent you an email, check your inbox.

Comment: Is this work for you?

Comment: I emailed you with what happened, please check that out.

Comment: @Shoaib posting your email for off site communications is totally inappropriate here. Defeats the whole purpose of this site

Comment: @charlietfl  you are right about that. he did that because none of us is able to use the chat feature yet. hopefully he deletes it since I got the email now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling an event for multiple objects, you need to be careful to handle only the object the event was fired on.

In your case you have an event callback on every select with the class `.changeStatus`. When any of those are changed, you post with the data

```
selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val()
```

Since `$('select.changeStatus')` gives you an array of all objects matching the selector, and `.val()` only returns the value for the first object in the array, you're effectively handling the first row only no matter which row was changed. Instead you need to use

```
selectFieldValue: $(this).val()
```

with `this` referring to the object the event was fired on.

Same goes for your alert; change `$('select.changeStatus').val()` to `$(this).val()`.

Final script with those changes would be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select.changeStatus').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'test2.php',
                data: {selectFieldValue: $(this).val(), order_Id:  $(this).siblings(".order_Id").val()},
//***only select that rows .order_Id by using $.siblings() with selector
                success: function(html){alert('Select field value has changed to' + $(this).val()); },
                dataType: 'html'
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your point makes sense actually. I tried your suggestion but seems to be something messing. do I need to define a  variable for "changeStatus" ? if yes please show me how.

Comment: @SarahFahad is same issue for the hidden input . You need the specific one for that form

Comment: can you show me the final script ? I will be appreciated.

Comment: I edited my post to include final code, including how to get that rows hidden input, like @charlietfl pointed out

Comment: It worked!! wow I'm very grateful thank you so much! but the alert msg stopped working I don't know what the reason is?

Comment: Well, truth is it really boils down to the same point; it never really worked. Think about it, `alert($('select.changeStatus').val());` will simply output the value of the first object in the `$('select.changeStatus')` array, namely, the value of your first row. It doesn't matter where that line's written or which row you had in mind.The reason my fix didn't work [I admit, I edited it without thinking ;-)] is because `this` in your callback function is no longer in the events scope and therefore doesn't point to the object that triggered the event.

Comment: I assume you don't really need that alert anymore. You'd want to handle the server's response; though I noticed you don't return anything in your php file...